# Propagate touchmove event from panel to content in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a link `myLink` on a side panel `myPanel` and some content `myContent`. I want to:

1. Touch `myLink` on `myPanel`, don't release the touch
2. `myPanel` closes
3. An event listener for `touchmove` is added to `myContent` (The current touch hasn't ended)
4. `myContent` handles the current touch as the `touchmove` it just started listening for

I'm doing 1 to 3 like this:

```
$( '#myLink' ).touchstart(function() {
  $( '#myPanel' ).panel( 'close' );
  // addEventListener for touchmove somewhere else 
});
```

I've tried triggering `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events before and after adding the listener, and nothing.

I have different things responding to `touchmove` within `myContent` at different times, so I want to add this specific listener only after `myLink` has been touched.

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, I've been looking for a while, but I guess I'm not familiar enough with the terminology.

Comment: instead of adding and removing events you can create a "flag object" (f = {panel: false, link: true}) and check for those flags in a single move event.

Comment: Can I read the coordinates of a `touchmove` within the content if the touch has started in the panel just using flags?

Comment: You will read them normally ... just use one event for touchmove and inside the event function make whatever tests you might need (make use of the event argument, i recommend using a switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of adding listeners for `touchmove` somewhere else, I bind `touchmove` to `myLink` and directly call what was being called outside:

```
$( '#myLink' ).bind('touchstart',function() {
  $( '#myPanel' ).panel( 'close' );
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Don't addEventListener for touchmove
});
$( '#myLink' ).bind('touchmove',function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // directly call what my previous listener was calling:
  external.onTouchMove(event);
});
```

The trick is using `originalEvent` when handling the event outside:

```
external.prototype.onTouchMove = function(e)
{
  var event = e.originalEvent;
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do what must be done
};
```